# Updating specific rows of a tensor matrix during gradient updation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, recommendation-engine

I have been trying to implement the paper: [SeER: An Explainable Deep Learning MIDI-based Hybrid Song Recommender System](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.01640.pdf).

So, what I have been doing is this:

Model Code:

```
class HybridFactorization(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    # embedding_size is also the number of lstm units
    # num_users, num_movies = input_shape
    # required_users: (batch_size, embedding_size)
    # songs_output: (batch_size, embedding_size)
    def __init__(self, embedding_size, num_users, num_tracks):        
        super(HybridFactorization, self).__init__()
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size    
        self.num_users = num_users
        self.num_tracks = num_tracks  
        self.required_users = None         
        self.U = self.add_weight("U", 
                                shape=[self.num_users, self.embedding_size], 
                                dtype=tf.float32,
                                initializer=tf.initializers.GlorotUniform)                        
        self.lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(self.embedding_size) 

    def call(self, user_index, songs_batch):
        output_lstm = self.lstm(songs_batch)

        self.required_users = self.U.numpy()
        self.required_users = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.required_users[np.array(user_index)],
                                              dtype=tf.float32)                             
        return tf.matmul(self.required_users, output_lstm, transpose_b=True)        


class HybridRecommender(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, embedding_size, num_users, num_tracks):
        super(HybridRecommender, self).__init__()
        self.HybridFactorization = HybridFactorization(embedding_size, 
                                                       num_users, num_tracks)        

    def call(self, user_index, songs_batch):
        output = self.HybridFactorization(user_index, songs_batch)        
        return output
```

Utility Functions and running the model:

```
def loss_fn(source, target):            
    mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()        
    return mse(source, target)

model = HybridRecommender(EMBEDDING_SIZE, num_users, num_tracks)
Xhat = model(user_index, songs_batch)        

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
EPOCHS = 1

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    start = time.time()
    total_loss = 0

    for (batch, (input_batch, target_batch)) in enumerate(train_dataset):            
        songs_batch = create_songs_batch(input_batch)
        user_index = input_batch[:, 0].numpy()
        X = create_pivot_batch(input_batch, target_batch)        

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            Xhat = model(user_index, songs_batch)
            batch_loss = loss_fn(X, Xhat)

        variables = model.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(batch_loss, variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))

        total_loss += batch_loss
```

Now, various functions like `create_songs_batch(input_batch)` and `create_pivot_batch(input_batch, target_batch)` just provide data in the required format.

My model runs but I get the warning:
`WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['U:0'] when minimizing the loss.`

Now, I can see why variable `U` is not being updated as there is no direct path to it.
I want to update some specific rows of `U` which are mentioned in `user_index` in every batch call.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to solve the problem by rather than copying some rows of `U` and trying to solve it. Instead, I used a temporary matrix that is one hot encoded form of `user_index` and multiplied it with `U` to desired results and it also removed the results.

Part of code that needs to be modified:

```
    def call(self, user_index, songs_batch):
        # output_lstm: (batch_size, emb_sz)
        # batch_encoding: (batch_size, num_users)
        # required_users: (batch_size, emb_sz)
        output_lstm = self.lstm(songs_batch)        

        user_idx = np.array(user_index)
        batch_encoding = np.zeros((user_idx.size, self.num_users))        
        batch_encoding[np.arange(user_idx.size), user_idx] = 1
        batch_encoding = tf.convert_to_tensor(batch_encoding, dtype=tf.float32)

        self.required_users = tf.matmul(batch_encoding, self.U)
        return tf.matmul(self.required_users, output_lstm, transpose_b=True)
```